# I am having trouble setting up billing cycles for Flask with Python

Tags: javascript, python, api, flask, paypal

For normal payments I am using a fix I had managed to make through the rest api. I am trying to create billing cycles now but whatever I do I get errors. Can someone help me set it up on Flask?

Basically I want to do the following:

- User clicks **JOIN NOW** button and they get displayed a page (already done that)
- On that page I would normally have the 2 PayPal buttons
  [image]
- Using the subscriptions/plans API I understand that is not possible. How could I do that.
  I want the user to click the buttons in JS, trigger a request to my server, handle the payment, register the user on the DB and then refresh the page so they can login to the dashboard. That is what I would do if it was a one-off payment. How can I do that with plans.

This is what I have written so far:

```
@app.route('/payment')
def payment():
    redirect(create_billing_agreement())

# HELPERS
def create_billing_agreement():
    billing_agreement = BillingAgreement({
        "name": 'Stocked Lab Subscription Agreement',
        'description': "Agreement for Stocked Lab Subscription Plan",
        'start_date': datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(),
        "plan": {'id': create_billing_plan()}})
    if billing_agreement.create():
        for link in billing_agreement.links:
            if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                redirect_url = str(link.href)
                return redirect_url
    else:
        print(billing_agreement.error)

def create_billing_plan():
    plan = BillingPlan({
        "name": 'Stocked Lab Subscription',
        'description': 'The base subscription for Stocked Lab',
        "type": 'INFINITE',
        "payment_definitions": [{
            "name": "Standard Plan",
            "type": "REGULAR",
            "frequency_interval": "1",
            "frequency": "MONTH",
            "cycles": '0',
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "15"
            }
        }],
        "merchant_preferences": {
            "auto_bill_amount": "yes",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:5000/cancel_subscription",
            "initial_fail_amount_action": "continue",
            "max_fail_attempts": "1",
            "return_url": "http://localhost:5000/",
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": '0'
        }
    })
    if plan.create():
        print(f'Billing Plan [{plan.id}] created successfully')
        if plan.activate():
            plan = BillingPlan.find(plan.id)
            print(f"Billing Plan [{plan.id}] state changed to {plan.state}")
            return plan.id
        else:
            print(plan.error)
    else:
        print(plan.error)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Passing a subscription plan to Smart Payment Buttons is explained here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#subscriptions-with-smart-payment-buttons